# IBM DB2 content manager database regarding query

Tags: db2-content-manager

In IBM DB2 content manager 8.6 , which all tables between two databases RMDB(Resource manager DB2 database) and ICMNLSDB (Library server DB2 database) are linked to each other to retrieve data stored.
Is Itemid column from table ICMADMIN.ICMSTITEMS001001 is referred as obj_itemid from rmadmin.rmobjects table as we don't find any table which is referred between each other. we need to retrieve the path of files stored in filesystem by IBM content manager.

I checked whether column "itemid" from ICMADMIN.ICMSTITEMS001001 table is referred as "obj_itemid" from rmadmin.rmobjects table but could not map any record. Please correct my understanding .